# How to run BigQuery query from android using google-cloud-bigquery library

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I want to get the data from BigQuery events table into my android device.

I have tried using the BigQuery Library but somehow it's not working even if I have tried with the credential.json file it is not working.
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.73.0'

If you can elaborate or share some reference link to run a query from an android device give me the link.

Thank you.

```
try {
        // Instantiate a client.
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credential).build().getService();*/
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                        "SELECT "
                                + "param1.value.string_value AS item_name,"
                                + "SUM(param2.value.double_value) AS quantity"
                                + "FROM `uniorder-prod.analytics_200255431.events_*`,"
                                + "UNNEST(event_params) AS param1,"
                                + "UNNEST(event_params) AS param2"
                                + "WHERE event_name = \"total_consumption_res\" AND"
                                + "param1.key = \"item_name\" AND"
                                + "param2.key = \"quantity\""
                                + "GROUP BY item_name"
                                + "ORDER BY quantity DESC")
                        // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
                        // See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/
                        .setUseLegacySql(false)
                        .build();

        // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
        JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

        // Wait for the query to complete.
        queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

        // Check for errors
        if (queryJob == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
        } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
            // You can also look at queryJob.getStatus().getExecutionErrors() for all
            // errors, not just the latest one.
            throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
        }

        // Get the results.
        QueryResponse response = bigquery.getQueryResults(jobId);

        TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults();

        // Print all pages of the results.
        for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
            String item_name = row.get("item_name").getStringValue();
            double quantity = row.get("quantity").getDoubleValue();
            System.out.printf("item_name: %s quantity: %d%n", item_name, quantity);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: "somehow it's not working" meaning...? Is there some kind of error? What is it? The odds of someone being able to help are higher if you give more detail beyond saying that something isn't working.

Comment: Wen I try to run BigQuery using BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService() it throws error
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
and When I try to run using BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credential).build().getService() it throws error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: where file is accessible but still throwing the error. (No such file or directory)

Comment: I have fixed the issue, Thanks :)